# GNU C Library (glibc) build error (libc-modules.h not found)

Tags: linux, makefile, glibc

I'm trying to build the latest version of glibc (2.22). I've not modified any sources of glibc. On my x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.1 machine I'm using the following extract of a makefile to build:

```
HOST ?= x86_64-linux-gnu
TARGET ?= x86_64-linux-gnu

CROSS_OUT = $(shell pwd)/$(TARGET)

CC ?= gcc
CXX ?= g++
LD ?= ld

[...]

CFLAGS ?= "-I$(CROSS_OUT)/include -L$(CROSS_OUT)/lib"
CXXFLAGS ?= "-I$(CROSS_OUT)/include -L$(CROSS_OUT)/lib"
CPPFLAGS ?= "-I$(CROSS_OUT)/include -L$(CROSS_OUT)/lib"
LDFLAGS ?= "-I$(CROSS_OUT)/include -L$(CROSS_OUT)/lib"

[...]

GLIBC_PATH=$(shell pwd)/glibc
GLIBC_BUILD_PATH=$(shell pwd)/glibc-build

glibc: glibc-clean
    mkdir -p $(GLIBC_BUILD_PATH)
    cd $(GLIBC_BUILD_PATH) && \
    CC=$(CC) \
    CXX=$(CXX) \
    LD=$(LD) \
    CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) \
    CXXFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS) \
    CPPFLAGS=$(CPPFLAGS) \
    LDFLAGS=$(LDFLAGS) \
    $(GLIBC_PATH)/configure \
    --host=$(TARGET) \
    --build=$(HOST) \
    --prefix=$(CROSS_OUT) \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-add-ons \
    --enable-static-nss && \
    make && \
    make install

glibc-clean:
    rm -r -f $(GLIBC_BUILD_PATH)
```

Make stops nearly immediatly with the following error:

```
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
../include/stdc-predef.h:64:1: fatal error: /home/leon/reaper/glibc-build/libc-modules.h: No such file or directory
 #endif
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Unfortunately, the file definitely doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you solve the problem (I have the same one)? 
-fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE in CFLAGS does not help.

Answer (score 2):

In met the same error when I used **--disable-shared** option for `configure`.
When I removed the option, the build passed correctly.
I also use `-fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` in CFLAGS according to glibc FAQ (my OS is Debian).
Also this topic was helpful to set up environment:
https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/07/msg00120.html

This is my script for build glibc:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sudo aptitude install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
# sudo aptitude install build-essentials
# sudo aptitude install gawk
export CFLAGS="-fPIC -O2 -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"
mkdir glibc-build
cd glibc-build
../glibc-2.23/configure --disable-werror --prefix=/home/alexey/projects/work/build-dir/glibc-prefix
make
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing these:

`$ sudo apt-get install build-essential`

`$ sudo apt-get install libc6`

And link from where you got that source code please.

Comment: They were already installed. I downloaded the source from the official ftp at [http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an alien libc6 / an extra libc6, the build of glibc-2.22 is described here http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html

Ref. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/

Suggest : `--prefix=/opt/glibc222`

---

The header 'libc-modules.h' is a generated header. Appears when configuring is done the right way.

---

[glibc222](/questions/tagged/glibc222)